# python pathlib resolve does not support Chinese character on windows

Tags: python, pathlib

On my windows,

```
pathlib.Path('R:/人')
```

has no problem to give

```
WindowsPath('R:/人')
```

However,

```
pathlib.Path('R:/人').resolve()
```

gives

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 pathlib.Path('R:/人').resolve()
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py in resolve(self, strict)    1178         if
> self._closed:    1179             self._raise_closed()
> -> 1180         s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)    1181         if s is None:    1182             # No symlink resolution => for
> consistency, raise an error if
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py in resolve(self, path, strict)
> 203                 while True:
> 204                     try:
> --> 205                         s = self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
> 206                     except FileNotFoundError:
> 207                         previous_s = s
>
> OSError: [WinError 1] 函数不正确。: 'R:\人'

**What is the problem with resolve in pathlib?**

On the other hand,

```
pathlib.Path('R:/人').absolute()
```

correctly gives

```
WindowsPath('R:/人')
```

Comment: Check the version of python. I hope this answer's your question:https://discuss.python.org/t/pathlib-absolute-vs-resolve/2573/4

Comment: @BhavinT My version is python 3.8.8. But it seems to be a different bug in the post you give.